# Simulate Autoregressive Conditional Poisson data

Tags: r, simulation

Currently, I am doing the simulation with Autoregressive conditional Poisson (ACP). To test whether my parameter estimator is better than MLE (by comparing the biasness), first, I have to generate ACP process. The process is given as:

```
X_t|F_(t-1)=Pois(lambda_t) and lambda_t=gamma+alpha * X_(t-1)+beta * lambda_(t-1)
```

The ACP package in R, just applicable for real data set (eg: Zeger 1988) and used for regression case. For me, i have to generate my own data set using ACP model. Could someone help me to generate autoregressive conditional Poisson (ACP) data using R software?

Comment: Me thinks this is what you need. https://statcompute.wordpress.com/2015/03/29/autoregressive-conditional-poisson-model-i/ Hopefully that helps.